# Stop and remove a SKScene from a View

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit

a have subclassed a SKScene and implemented `didMoveToView` which did nothing at the moment. Empty function body. Let's name the class TestScene for a moment. 
I also have a WindowController and a var named testScene:

```
var testScene: TestScene?
```

To functions are implemented `show`and `hide`

The show function looks like this:

```
func show(){
     testScene = TestScene(fileNamed:"TestScene")
}
```

fileNamed:"TestScene" is of course the .sks file with a animation.
The hide function looks like this:

```
func hide(){
    if let scene = testScene {
        scene.paused = true
    }
    testScene?.removeFromParent()
    testScene = nil
    self.close()
}
```

This SpriteKit scene does appear on circumstances (button click) in my application. And after the execution is disappears. 
Everything is working fine so far.

If I'll press the button the animation comes into the view and close after hide() is triggered, BUT: **Since the button is pressed and**

```
testScene = TestScene(fileNamed:"TestScene")
```

**is executed**, i got 0.5% CPU load. Even after `hide`. I can in commend the TestScene() and the CPU falls down to 0% after a little peak.
( i do some more stuff in that buttonPressed: function). So I am pretty sure that the `TestScene` is not removed after hide is called and maybe do some *crazy shit* in the background. 
The Problem is, that the whole FinalScene will produce 5% of CPU and after the first appearance this load won't go away. :(

My Question is: How to remove the SKScene from the execution loop?

Thanks a lot for any advice, i debug this since hours by now and can't figure out how to dismiss the ended animation.

ps.

Comment: I also tried to add removeAllActions, but no effect. CPU is still high.

Comment: Make sure you also remove the `testScene` object from memory, you may enter to a retain loop with it

Comment: By the way, you are creating a `TestScene` in the `show()` method, and removing a `NGCuckooScene` in the `hide()` method. Do you really mean to do that?

Comment: Does `TestScene` has any delegates, shared properties, etc.. Anything that doesn't let it deallocate? A good way to test if it's being deallocated is overriding `dealocate` method and printing something, setting a breakpoint...

Comment: cool tip. thanks. But only SpriteKit.SKScene is shown in the debugger.

Comment: this is swift, you need to override `deinit` not deallocate.

Comment: I uploaded a testproject that shows the behaviour. See https://github.com/petershaw/SKBugExample Run this Project, klick notthing and ake a look at the Activity Monitor. SKBugExample takes 0% of the CPU. Now klick the red icon in the taskbar and wait 5sec. It consumes 3.2% now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If i remove the SKView from the xib. Everything is fine. :( Even without a outlet, or a animation. The pure existance of the SKView in the xib procuces the cpu load. even after the window is closes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to explizit remove the SKView-subview:

```
animationView.removeFromSuperview()
```

This means that we have to build the view from the xib on every event, because the view is lost. The other possibility is to add the SKView programatically on show().